# mock requests post responses __dict__ and status_code python

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking

I need to mock a request.post with both `status_code` and `__dict__`. I tried this

```
    @patch("tests.requests.post", Autospec=True)
    def test_create_job(self,, mock_post):
        mock_post.return_value = Mock(status_code=200, __dict__={"a": "b"})
```

without success, I tried this one also `mock_post.return_value.__dict__ = {'a': 'b'}` and works but not when I want also the 200

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
mock_post.return_value.__dict__ = {'a': 'b', status_code=200}
```

But this way you replace the dictionary with all of `Mock` attributes, after which you won't be able to call for example `assert_called_once_with` method.

Why do are you trying to set custom `__dict__`? Why not:

```
mock_post.return_value = 200
mock_post.a = 'b'
```

or

```
mock_post.return_value = Mock(return_value=200, a=b)
```

Comment: I need `__dict__` because it is a requests response and I am using values inside it

Comment: I don't get what you mean